# Imprimir mais que um valor com json

Tags: json

Como é que eu posso mostrar o nome, a idade e a cidade ao mesmo tempo na tela e não só o nome?

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.name;
```

faz com que mostre so o nome dentro desse obj mas eu queria que aparece-se toda a informação sobre esse obj.

```js
// Storing data:
myObj = {name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"};
myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
localStorage.setItem("testJSON", myJSON);

// Retrieving data:
text = localStorage.getItem("testJSON");
obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você concatenar os valores que pretende imprimir.

```js
// Storing data:
obj = {name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"};

// document.body.innerHTML = obj.name + " " + obj.age + " " + obj.city;
document.body.innerHTML = `${obj.name} ${obj.age} ${obj.city}`;
```

[Veja este artigo](http://2ality.com/2011/10/string-concatenation.html)

Comment: Resultou! Obrigado!

Comment: @DavidMv só não se esqueça de marcar esta resposta como correta, assim as  pessoas que estiverem com o mesmo problema também podem ser ajudadas

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer assim:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.name,obj.age,obj.city;
```

Só usei JSON com C#, então acho que a lógica é parecida

Comment: Já tentei isso e tambem nao funciona :( mas obrigado na mesma